# SAS select records (or columns) where the value sums up to a specific number

Tags: sas

I have a table containing values like this

```
a        b
110      1024
120      987
130      456
140      312
```

Is it possible in SAS to find all combinations of variable b that sum up to a specific value?

Comment: This is a variation of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Although finding and listing all the valid combinations is straightforward, there is no known way of doing it quickly for a large list of items. Please do some research and attempt your own implementation, and ask a more specific question if there's a particular part of it that gives you bother.

Comment: Also, [obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/287/)

Comment: Do you have access to SAS/OR? [proc optmodel](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ormpug/63352/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ormpug_optmodel_sect073.htm) is suited to this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

As user667489 has said in the comments this is not a simple problem. For a small number of values, you can try the following  approach:

```
data test;
    do i= 1 to 20;
        b=int(abs(rand('norm', 0, 1)) * 10);
        output;
    end;
run;

proc transpose data = test out = testFormatted prefix=b;
    id i;
    var b;
run;

data _null_;
    set testFormatted;
    array values [*] b:;
    numValues = dim(values);
    length workingComb $32676;

    do k = 1 to numValues;
        combNum = comb(numValues, k);
        do i = 1 to combNum;
            rc=lexComb(i, k, of values[*]);
            result = 0;
            workingComb = '';
            do j = 1 to k;
                result = result + values[j];
            end;
            if result = 100 then do;
                do m = 1 to k;
                    workingComb = catx(' ', workingComb, put(values[m],best.));
                end;
                put 'Combination found: ' rc=  k= workingComb= result=;
                output;
            end;                    
        end;
    end;
run;
```